# How can I extend Decodable to initialise from dictionary?

Tags: swift, extension-methods, decodable

I want to extend Decodable so I can create a new instance of a Codable class from a dictionary of values.

```
extension Decodable {
    init(from dictionary: [String : Codable]) throws {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])
        let newSelf = try JSONDecoder().decode(self.type, from: data)

        self = newSelf
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error `Value of type 'Self' has no member 'type'` on the line that starts with `let newSelf = ...`

How should I provide the type to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.type` must be a concrete type, not a protocol. And you cannot create an instance of `Decodable` anyway.

What you can do is to create a generic `decode` method which takes a dictionary as parameter for example

```
func decode<T : Decodable>(from dictionary: [String : Decodable]) throws -> T {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}


struct Person : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let age : Int
}

let dict : [String:Decodable] = ["name" : "Foo", "age" : 30]

let person : Person = try! decode(from: dict)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.